# Java Arrays.binarySearch on a two-dimensional int[][] with Comparator.comparingInt()

Tags: java, binary-search

I have a 2D array of int and want to use Arrays.binarySearch() to find a the first array with a specific second element, irrespective of the value of the first element but I don' I am unable to figure out the correct syntax.

I though it should be the same syntax as used in Arrays.sort() with a custom comparator, but evidently I am incorrect :)

Here is some sample code:

```
int[][] a = new int[][]{ {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6}, {9, -1} } ;

//first sort the array
Arrays.sort(a, Comparator.comparingInt((int[] i) -> i[1]));

// after sorting the array is now: {9,-1}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {3,6}
//this won't compile, should return 0 since a[0] is the only element with a second element equal to 2
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(a, 2, Comparator.comparingInt( (int[] i) -> i[1] ));
```

The error I get is:

```
Error:(14, 15) java: no suitable method found for binarySearch(int[][],int,java.util.Comparator<int[]>)
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>binarySearch(T[],T,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: java.io.Serializable
        upper bound(s): java.io.Serializable,int[],java.lang.Object)
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>binarySearch(T[],int,int,T,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Could someone help me with the correct syntax for Arrays.binarySearch()?

Thanks!

Comment: In that generic, `T` is an `int[]`, which means that the second parameter must be an `int[]`, but you're passing an `int`. Change second parameter from `2` to `new int[] { 0, 2 }`. --- Then make sure you capture the return value from `binarySearch(...)`, otherwise what's the point.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Perhaps my question wasn't clear so I added an example. I am searching for a specific `int[2] pair` where `pair[1] == 2`

Comment: Just curious, but why all the down votes? What can I improve to make this a better question?

Comment: If you do what I said, the code will compile, and run, and it will set `index = 1` because, after the sort, the array will be `{ {0,-1}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6} }` and hence the pair with `pair[1] == 2` is at index **1**.

Comment: I misunderstood and though that using {0,2} would literally search for {0,2} but I see that only the second value is used. Using {any value, 2} works. I never would have guess this. Thanks! If you post your comment as a solution I'll be very happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks you so much for asking this and answering this. I was so confused and lost with exactly this issue. A big thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andreas was kind enough to offer this solution:

> In that generic, T is an int[], which means that the second parameter
>   must be an int[], but you're passing an int. Change second parameter
>   from 2 to new int[] { 0, 2 }. --- Then make sure you capture the
>   return value from binarySearch(...), otherwise what's the point.

I hadn't realized that even though you pass in an exact value as the target parameter, it's possible to ignore it, or just use a property of the target, for the binary search. In my example I was looking for any int[] with where the value at index 1 is 2, so it doesn't matter what value we have at index 0; we can set it to anything.